# Insert the outcome of a formula using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert a formula in a range of cells in column P. Afterwards I want the outcome of the formula to be a hard value (so not the formula but the outcome). At the moment I'm placing the formula in the cells, then autofill to last row and then copy column and past special. I want to avoid using select - copy - paste. I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this, I've seen it before but can't find it anymore.

The code I'm using at the moment

```
Set frCP = Worksheets("Compliance").Range("P" & FirstRowFill & ":P" & LastRowMatchC)


With Worksheets("Compliance")
    .Range("P" & FirstRow).Offset(1).FormulaArray = "=IF(IFERROR(INDEX(Input!$A$2:A$" & LastRowInput & ",MATCH(1,SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(Input!$A$2:A$" & LastRowInput & "),O" & FirstRowOffset1 & "),0),0),W" & FirstRowOffset1 & ")=0,""ZZ"",IFERROR(INDEX(Input!$A$2:A$" & LastRowInput & ",MATCH(1,SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(Input!$A$2:A$" & LastRowInput & "),O" & FirstRowOffset1 & "),0),0),W" & FirstRowOffset1 & "))"
    .Range("P" & FirstRow).Offset(1).AutoFill Destination:=frCP
End With

Columns("P:P").Select
Range("P88").Activate
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

With Worksheets("Compliance")
    .Range("A" & FirstRow).Rows(ActiveCell.Row).AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
    .Range("P" & FirstRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
End With
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Compliance").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the result of your formula in `frCP` range rather than the formula?

Comment: @Zac, yes that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to replace the whole select-copy-paste block with:

```
columns("P:P").value = columns("P:P").value
```

I'm reading the question correctly, this should also work:

```
frCP.value = frCP.value
```